# Unable to run the jar file stored in GCS bucket using cloud shell command

Tags: java, jar, google-cloud-storage, dataflow, google-cloud-shell

I have stored one jar file in gcs bucket which launches dataflow job. I want to run that jar file from cloud shell command.

I am using below command to run jar file:

```
java -jar gs://TestBucket/lib/jar_file.jar func123 --runner=dataflow --project=project123 --bigtableInstanceId=bt-instance --bigtableTableId=tab123 --outputPrefix=gs://TestBucket1/data/output123 --stagingLocation=gs://TestBucket1/staging --hashTableOutputDir=gs://TestBucket1/dir1 --tempLocation=gs://TestBucket1/temp --region=us-central1
```

And getting below error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile gs://TestBucket/lib/jar_file.jar
```

I have rechecked the jar file path and it is correct. Can anyone help me if this because *"java -jar"* command does not support gs:// file or any bucket permission issue or something else?

Answer (score 2):

gs:// isn't a local file system and Java can't access it. If you want to do something similar, and you are on a linux environment, you can try to use [GCSFuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse). It mounts a GCS bucket as a logical file system on your linux filesystem tree. There are limitations but it should work for JAR

Comment: @Josesph N any progress? If the above answer helps you. Please consider accepting the answer and up voting it.

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere, thanks for your response. i am trying to run that command inside cloud function. so, not sure gcsfuse will work for me. but i'll check if any other ways are possible. thanks for surity that java will not support "gs://" files   :)

Comment: Except if you run java cloud functions you can't be sure that java is installed on the Cloud Functions runtime environment. If you have to customize your runtime environment, I strongly recommend to have a look to Cloud Run and its container support. It also supports GCSFuse mount in the gen2 runtime environment.